# R: How to group sequences based on value from an other column

Tags: r

**--EDITED--**

I have a dataframe like the example below.

```
+--------+-------------------------------+-----------+------------+
| userID |           timestamp           |  medium   | conversion |
+--------+-------------------------------+-----------+------------+
| us001  | 2019-01-18T00:11:55.385+00:00 | cpc       |          0 |
| us001  | 2019-01-18T00:12:35.385+00:00 | organic   |          1 |
| us001  | 2019-01-19T00:15:25.385+00:00 | referral  |          0 |
| us001  | 2019-01-19T00:15:25.385+00:00 | social    |          0 |
| us001  | 2019-01-19T00:17:25.385+00:00 | organic   |          0 |
| us002  | 2019-01-19T00:17:20.385+00:00 | organic   |          0 |
| us003  | 2019-01-18T00:11:55.385+00:00 | cpc       |          0 |
| us003  | 2019-01-18T00:12:35.385+00:00 | cpc       |          0 |
| us003  | 2019-01-19T00:15:25.385+00:00 | orgnanic  |          1 |
| us003  | 2019-01-19T00:15:25.385+00:00 | referral  |          0 |
| us003  | 2019-01-19T00:17:25.385+00:00 | referral  |          0 |
+--------+-------------------------------+-----------+------------+
```

What I am trying to do is to group the sequences based on time, but I want to break the sequence based on conversion as well.

So the result will look like the example below.

```
+--------+----------------------------+------------+
| userID |          sequence          | conversion |
+--------+----------------------------+------------+
| us001  | cpc > organic              |          1 |
| us001  | referra > social > organic |          0 |
| us002  | organic                    |          0 |
| us003  | cpc > cpc > organic        |          1 |
| us003  | referra > referral         |          0 |
+--------+----------------------------+------------+
```

I use the code below to create the sequence and group the rows based on userID and time.

```
groupedData <- gadata %>% 
               arrange(userID, timeDate) %>% 
               group_by(userID) %>% 
               mutate(sequence = paste0(medium, collapse = " > "))
```

But I struggle to group the data using the second value from the column conversion.

**Edit**

What I am trying to achieve is to group the sequence until a conversion gets recorded and equal to 1. If then the same user visits the site again after the last visit when s/he converted, then the next visits after the conversion should be grouped as a new separate sequence for the same user until another conversion gets recorded. I hope that makes more sense.

Every raw in the dataframe is a visit, not every visit leads to a conversion. So a lot of visits will have a conversion value "0". The moment a user converts the value of conversion will change to 1. But the conversion only applies to that single visit. However, a user may visit the site multiple times before they decide to convert. That is why not all visits before the conversion vist have a value of 1.

**Edit ends**

This dataset is to be used with the "markovchain" package in case that helps.

I am not very experienced with R. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to remove `gadata$` in `group_by`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thank you @akrun. Yes, I see that the gadata$ is not needed. I will remove it.

Comment: I am a bit confused about your results. If you were to `group_by` the `conversion` then for user `us001` with `conversion` 1 there is no `cpc`

Comment: Thank you for your comment @camnesia. It seems I did a bad job explaining the problem. What I am trying to achieve is to group the sequence until a conversion gets recorded and equal to 1. If then the same user visits the site again after the last visit when s/he converted, then the next visits after the conversion should be grouped as a new separate sequence for the same user until another conversion gets recorded. I hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused about either what the results should be or how the data should be. To get the results you want, the data should be modified, as you cannot `group_by` `conversion` and display `conversion` 1 for us001 with `medium` as cpsc and organic when in your data, cpc has `medium` 0 for us001. The modified data should look like this.

[image]

```
 gadata <- tibble(userID = c('us001','us001','us001','us001','us001','us002','us003','us003','us003','us003','us003'),
               timeDate = c('2019-01-18T00:11:55.385+00:00','2019-01-18T00:12:35.385+00:00','2019-01-19T00:15:25.385+00:00','2019-01-19T00:15:25.385+00:00',
                            '2019-01-19T00:17:25.385+00:00','2019-01-19T00:17:20.385+00:00','2019-01-18T00:11:55.385+00:00','2019-01-18T00:12:35.385+00:00',
                            '2019-01-19T00:15:25.385+00:00','2019-01-19T00:15:25.385+00:00','2019-01-19T00:17:25.385+00:00'),
               medium = c('cpc','organic','referral','social','organic','organic','cpc','cpc','orgnanic','referral','referral'),
               conversion = c(1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0))
```

In that case the data would be grouped by both `userID` and `conversion`.(Note that in you table a column is called `timestamp` but in your code `timeDate`)

```
groupedData <- gadata %>% 
      group_by(userID, conversion) %>% 
      arrange(userID, timeDate) %>% 
      summarise(sequence = paste0(medium, collapse = " > ")) %>%
      select(userID, sequence, conversion) %>%
      arrange(userID, desc(conversion))
```

Then the results are as you asked:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the confusion. I edited the original post and I added additional information to explain the problem in detail.